# MongoDB, indexing query in inner object and grouping?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, grouping, aggregation

My collection has ~7M documents and I need to perform grouping queries on them.

I have documents like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5cba0179577fa92b9b6b36e8"),
  "demographics" : [
    {
      "key" : "country_code",
      "value" : "DE"
    },
    {
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "male"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5cba0179577fa92b9b6b36e9"),
  "demographics" : [
    {
      "key" : "country_code",
      "value" : "US"
    },
    {
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "female"
    },
    {
      "key" : "sport",
      "value" : "yes"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to do 2 different grouping counters:

#### 1. Count number of documents by `demographics.key`

```
db.panelUsers.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$demographics"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          demographic_key: "$demographics.key"
        },
        "count": {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

#### 2. Count number of documents by combinations `demographics.key`/`demographics.value`

```
db.panelUsers.explain().aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$demographics"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          demographic_key: "$demographics.key",
          demographic_value: "$demopgraphics.value"
        },
        "count": {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

I have created this index to try to make the query to be optimal:

```
{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
    "demograhics.key" : 1.0,
    "demographics.value" : 1.0
  },
  "name" : "demograhics.key_1_demographics.value_1",
  "ns" : "panelhub.panelUsers"
}
```

But when I look to the `explain()` of both queries I don't see the index to be used:

#### 1.

```
{
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {},
        "fields" : {
          "demographics" : 1,
          "_id" : 0
        },
        "queryPlanner" : {
          "plannerVersion" : 1,
          "namespace" : "panelhub.panelUsers",
          "indexFilterSet" : false,
          "parsedQuery" : {},
          "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "direction" : "forward"
          },
          "rejectedPlans" : []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind" : {
        "path" : "$demographics"
      }
    },
    {
      "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
          "demographic_key" : "$demographics.key"
        },
        "count" : {
          "$sum" : {
            "$const" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1.0
}
```

#### 2.

```
{
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {},
        "fields" : {
          "demographics" : 1,
          "demopgraphics.value" : 1,
          "_id" : 0
        },
        "queryPlanner" : {
          "plannerVersion" : 1,
          "namespace" : "panelhub.panelUsers",
          "indexFilterSet" : false,
          "parsedQuery" : {},
          "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "direction" : "forward"
          },
          "rejectedPlans" : []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind" : {
        "path" : "$demographics"
      }
    },
    {
      "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
          "demographic_key" : "$demographics.key",
          "demographic_value" : "$demopgraphics.value"
        },
        "count" : {
          "$sum" : {
            "$const" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1.0
}
```

How can I index these queries, or what I have to change in the query to use my index?

Comment: Pretty much the only things that can utilize an index in an aggregation pipeline are either `$match`, `$sort`, `$geoNear` and only ever in the **very first stage** where the "shape of the documents" has not been altered in any way by other processing. Nothing else can access an index to speed queries, and `$unwind` is absolutely **the worst thing** you could ever begin an aggregation pipeline with, since it exponentially increases the documents to be processed. In fact, if your common pattern is indeed `$unwind` first, then you really should separate the data to another collection instead.

Comment: Is there any way I can improve my queries to add them some performance and it is not create another separated collection? My objective is basically count the unique appearances of each `demographics.key` and `demographics.key`/`demographics.value) (In my production scenario creating another collection is not an option)

Comment: If the content is in an array where you require the grouping key from within those items then you have no other choice but to `$unwind` unless you move that content into a separate collection instead of the array. Also you have nothing in your desired operations that would benefit from a `$match` stage to filter and reduce results. In all honesty for the sort of numbers you are talking about you probably should be "pre-aggregating" as data is written instead of relying on any computed aggregation statements. You're basically accumulating "counters", and that is almost instant per write.